# pyDES encrypt() output could not be copies correctly

Tags: python

I'm trying to create encrypt & decrypt functions using pyDES module.

Problem:

if I print the cipher text on the screen then copy it (CTRL+C) then put it as input for the decrypt() function I get the following exception:

```
ValueError: Invalid data length, data must be a multiple of 8 bytes
```

my code:

```
key = "12345678"
charset = "utf-8"
def encrypt():
    msg = input("Enter message: ")
    data = des(key, CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
    cipherText = data.encrypt(msg.encode(charset))
    print(cipherText)
def decrypt():
    cipherText = input("Enter cipher text: ")
    data = des(key, CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
    decrypted = data.decrypt(cipherText).decode(charset)
    print(decrypted)
```

While passing the cipherText directly to decrypt message (not by copying it manually from the screen) it works perfectly! like this:

```
key = "12345678"
charset = "utf-8"
msg = input("Enter message: ")
data = des(key, CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
cipherText = data.encrypt(msg.encode(charset))
print(cipherText)
decrypted = data.decrypt(cipherText).decode(charset)
print(decrypted)
```

fix/explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: The obvious question is to find what length your pasted text is. Could it be carry line ends etc?

Comment: passing the cipher text directly to the decrypt() function works perfectly which indicates that the cipher text length is correct. yet printing then copying it from the screen will change the length significantly, so I guess we are dealing with formatting\encoding issue here. However I don't know what is the real problem :(